# On hover of table row, make font size of element bigger while keeping the height of the table row the same

Tags: html, css

The issue that I am having is when I hover over the value in the table row, and the font size increases, so does the height of the table row.

I would like for only the font size to increase on hover, and not the table row height. I've tried messing with line-height, max-height in the table, td, tr, tr:hover css to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
table {
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: #996600;
  background: #000066;
  z-index: -47;
}

td {
  font-size: 2.4em;
  padding: 1em, 1em, 1em, 1em;
  font-family: -apple-system, 'Raleway', '.SFNSText-Regular', 'Arimo', 'FreeSans', 'Oxygen', 'Nimbus Sans L', 'Liberation Sans', 'Helvetica Neue LT Std', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'ITCKorinnaW03-Kursiv', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  height: 2.4em;
  color: #FF0;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-decoration: bold;
  z-index: -47;
}

td:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size:2.8em; /*this is the font size I want to increase to on hover, without affecting height of row.*/
}
```

````html
<table>
      <thead>
        <th>
          CATEGORY
        </th>
      </thead>
      <tr id="row_1">
        <td id="cell_1A">
          $100
        </td>
        <td>
          $100
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```
````

Comment: A much cleaner and pleasant looking way would be to wrap your content in td in a div, and use something like `transform: scale(1.2);` on the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change also the height on hover:

```css
table {
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: #996600;
  background: #000066;
  z-index: -47;
}

td {
  font-size: 2.4em;
  padding: 1em, 1em, 1em, 1em;
  font-family: -apple-system, 'Raleway', '.SFNSText-Regular', 'Arimo', 'FreeSans', 'Oxygen', 'Nimbus Sans L', 'Liberation Sans', 'Helvetica Neue LT Std', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'ITCKorinnaW03-Kursiv', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  height: 2.4em;
  color: #FF0;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-decoration: bold;
  z-index: -47;
}

td:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size:2.8em; 
  height: 2em;  /* more precisely it should be (2.4x2.4)/2.8  */
}
```

```html
<table>
      <thead>
        <th>
          CATEGORY
        </th>
      </thead>
      <tr id="row_1">
        <td id="cell_1A">
          $100
        </td>
        <td>
          $100
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your height `em` to `rem`, so it is determined by the global value not the locally changing on hover value. Might as well change it all to `rem` to simplify it. Also, I would remove the padding and just let it center itself with `vertical-align: middle`.

```css
table {
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: #996600;
  background: #000066;
  z-index: -47;
}

td {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: -apple-system, 'Raleway', '.SFNSText-Regular', 'Arimo', 'FreeSans', 'Oxygen', 'Nimbus Sans L', 'Liberation Sans', 'Helvetica Neue LT Std', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'ITCKorinnaW03-Kursiv', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  height: 4.4rem;
  color: #FF0;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-decoration: bold;
  z-index: -47;
}

td:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size:2.8rem; /*this is the font size I want to increase to on hover, without affecting height of row.*/
}
```

````html
<table>
      <thead>
        <th>
          CATEGORY
        </th>
      </thead>
      <tr id="row_1">
        <td id="cell_1A">
          $100
        </td>
        <td>
          $100
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```
````